# laravel - how to lock page by hour of day

Tags: php, laravel

I need to prevent user from access certain pages from 9am to 6pm.

So, what is the best way to achieve this? Should I create an Middleware? Or a kernel condition? Or add condition to controllers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Middleware is definitely the right place for a feature like this.

Full [documentation is here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#introduction).

The quick version:

1. `php artisan make:middleware TimeRestrictedMiddleware` - this will create a file in app/Http/Middleware called `TimeRestrictedMiddleware.php`
2. Inside that file's `handle()` method write some code to check your time restrictions and return a view/response to reject the user.

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Carbon::now()->format('H') >= 9 && Carbon::now()->format('H') <= 18) {
            //
            return response(view('some-view-to-deny'));
        }
        // default behaviour  
        return $next($request);
    }
```

3. Add the reference to new middleware - `$routeMiddleware` inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`
4. Then wrap your routes with the middleware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['time-restricted']], function () {
    // all routes that need time-restrictions
});
```

Comment: Nice approach. You could even go a step further and make the start and end hour params for the middleware :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
public function returnViewName(){
   if(Carbon::now()->format('H') >= 9 && Carbon::now()->format('H') =< 18){
      return;
   } else {
      return view('viewName');
   }
}
```

Code is untested but should get you there.

Comment: Careful, `h` (lowercase) is for 12-hour  formatting

Comment: Nvm, you caught it :)

Comment: you're right. after i saw your answer, i realized my error and corrected my post. thanks for looking out :)

Comment: That `||` might bite us

Comment: how can I apply this for many routes?

Comment: @anderlaini If you need it in multiple routes, I'd apply the same approach to a middleware

Comment: @WesleySmith is right. if you want this over many routes, create a middleware and then put all the routes in question in a group. Then all those routes will be bound to that middleware

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
public function showPage(): View
{
    $hour = Carbon::now()->format('H');
    $template = $hour > 8 && $hour < 19 ? 'error-page' : 'actual-page';
    return view($template);
}
```